# C# output excel format

Tags: c#, output

I was wondering if anyone knows how to get output from `C#` in a `.txt` or `.xlsx` ?

I have written my code and a vector of double type must be my output in excel or in .txt.

Comment: Do you want to write a `String` to a text file?

Comment: Probably the simplest thing you can do is to write the values in a .csv (comma separated values) which can be directly opened in excel.

Comment: take  a look at epplus - a nice package for reading/ writing xlsx without excel acutally installed

Answer (score 0):

For txt file you can just use `File.AppendAllText(@"your path goes here/filename.txt", "line of text");`

Answer (score 0):

In order to export in xlsx format, I would definitely go with [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Also as an answer: http://epplus.codeplex.com/
It is a nice package for reading/ writing xlsx

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was a specific reason :-) I use this package a lot and I like it - thanks anyway ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You can output to the CSV file format. This is loadable by Excel.

Or you can use Excel Interop.